# Updating JTable after adding new values to database

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, sql-update, tablemodel

I have a JTable. I get the table values from database. I am adding some values to my database and want to refresh the JTable. for refreshing I am using this.

```
               try {
                buildTableModel(rs).fireTableDataChanged();
                table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
                table.repaint();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But when I use it my table disappears. What am I doing wrong? I searched google but couldnt find any solutions.

This is my table model;

```
 public  DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

Comment: You should only need `table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));`, as changing the model will trigger the table to update itself. It's impossible to know what "could" be going wrong with the out-of-context code snippet, but as a wild guess, you're re-using a pre-existing `ResultSet` which has already reached the end of the set, so it can't be looped over again (`rs.next` returns `false`), in which case, you should be re-querying the database for a new/fresh version of the `ResultSet`

Comment: Do you need buildTableModel(rs).fireTableDataChanged();?

Comment: I dont need it. When I use only ' table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs)); '   my table disappears.  @orabis

Comment: Then something else is wrong with your program and it's time to do some debugging, if only to isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I solved the problem with you wild guess. I just added **rs = null;**  **rs = st.executeQuery(sorgu);**  before  **table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs)); ** So I reset ResultSet and build it again for everytime I want to update my JTable.  I am not sure if its the correct way but working fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: @TurgutTak That should trigger a NullPointerException, what you should be doing is re-querying the database

Comment: @MadProgrammer  right.  my final code is  ` rs = null;

    try {
     
     rs = st.executeQuery(sorgu);
     table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } `

Comment: All code should be in your question itself since code loses its formatting in comments, making it hard to read.  And you'll want to delete any lines that are not necessary and only serve to confuse, such as the `// TODO...` line.

Comment: Do not use `ResultSet`s as fields. They should have very limited and short-lived scope; the common idiom is to declare them within the method that queries the data, and within a `try-with-resources` block.

Comment: A `ResultSet` is only a way to access the data which has previously been queried. This means, even if the database is updated, the queried `ResultSet` will not change, as it's a snapshot at the time the query was made. If you think the database has been changed, you will need to generate a new `ResultSet` by re-querying the database. If your database/driver supports mutable `ResultSet`s, you could make a `TableModel` which uses the `ResultSet` directly, allowing you to update the `ResultSet` and database directly. This doesn't account for someone else updating the database though

Comment: If your table is on a JPannel, you Can use JPannel.removeall(), then Use JPannel revalidate() and repaint ()